# How to find common fileds from all tables in a database?

Tags: mysql, inner-join, database-schema

I am trying to find a way to get all the common fields from all the tables in the database.
This is my code

```
SELECT t.TABLE_NAME 
FROM information_schema.TABLES t
INNER JOIN information_schema.COLUMNS c 
   ON t.TABLE_NAME=c.TABLE_NAME
WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA = '<database_name>'
   AND c.COLUMN_NAME = '<column_name>'
GROUP BY t.TABLE_NAME
```

And i want to do the same without typing the specific column name.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

```
SELECT col,cnt from (
SELECT c.COLUMN_NAME col, count(*) cnt
FROM information_schema.TABLES t
INNER JOIN information_schema.COLUMNS c 
   ON t.TABLE_NAME=c.TABLE_NAME
WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA = '<database_name>'
GROUP BY c.COLUMN_NAME 
) tbl WHERE cnt>=2;
```

Comment: Yes, and from all the columns from all the tables i want to get the common columns

Comment: OK, i got some result, but i don't think it's correct. Maximum number of counts should be 23. I have 23 tables in my DB. So a column of the same name can be maximum repeated 23 times. And i receive a count number of 105.